# GKE `ResourceQuota` on a namespace - limit higher than specified

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, quota

I have a Kubernetes cluster running on GKE, and I created a new namespace with a `ResourceQuota`:

yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: bot-quota
spec:
  hard:
    requests.cpu: '500m'
    requests.memory: 1Gi
    limits.cpu: '1000m'
    limits.memory: 2Gi
```

which I apply to my namespace (called `bots`), which gives me `kubectl describe resourcequota --namespace=bots`:

```
Name:            bot-quota
Namespace:       bots
Resource         Used  Hard
--------         ----  ----
limits.cpu       0     1
limits.memory    0     2Gi
requests.cpu     0     500m
requests.memory  0     1Gi


Name:                       gke-resource-quotas
Namespace:                  bots
Resource                    Used  Hard
--------                    ----  ----
count/ingresses.extensions  0     5k
count/jobs.batch            0     10k
pods                        0     5k
services                    0     1500
```

This is what I expect - and my expectation is that the `bots` namespace is hard limited to above limits.

Now I would like to deploy a single pod onto that namespace, using this simple yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: podname
  namespace: bots
  labels:
    app: someLabel
spec:
  nodeSelector:
    cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: default-pool
  containers:
    - name: containername
      image: something-image-whatever:latest
      resources:
        requests:
          memory: '96Mi'
          cpu: '300m'
        limits:
          memory: '128Mi'
          cpu: '0.5'
      args: ['0']
```

Given the `resources` specified`, I'd expect to be well in range, deploying a single instance. When I apply the yaml though:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "pod.yaml": pods "podname" is forbidden: exceeded quota: bot-quota, requested: limits.cpu=2500m, used: limits.cpu=0, limited: limits.cpu=1
```

If I change the pod's yaml to use a cpu limit of `0.3`, then the same error appear with `limits.cpu=2300m` requested.

In other words: it seems to miraculously add 2000m (=2) cpu to my limit.

We do NOT have any `LimitRange` applied.

What am I missing?

Comment: This is what I expect - and my expectation is that the bots namespace is hard limited to above limits. ---> You expect bot-quota to be same as gke resource quota is that what you mean ?

Comment: Is that the full yaml...you have only one container or more?

Comment: This seems odd indeed, have you tried with `cpu: "500m"` under limits?

Comment: @TarunKhosla The output I show there is what I expect, so I think the `ResourceQuota` is applied correctly (specifically: it has `limits.cpu` at 1) (I just included the full output to show that there aren't any other quotas)

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu yes, that is the full yaml. I tried to keep it as simple as possible to show the problem

Comment: @pst yes, same problem

Comment: Works completely fine for me , I tried this with your yaml , nginx image and your resource quota.

Comment: thanks @TarunKhosla - I will try to dig in deeper on my cluster/namespace setup, there must be something somewhere...

Comment: What is you GKE version?

Comment: @KoopaKiller master is on 1.16.13-gke.1 as is the nodepool I am deploying to

Comment: I've reproduced in my lab test, with the same GKE version and using your yamls files. Everything works fine. Try to create a new NS and apply the quota to see if it works. Ler me know.

Comment: FYI, we were able to narrow it down, it seems to only happen on istio-enabled namespaces... will update here if we find more

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments above, it is indeed related to `istio`. How?

As it is (now) obvious, the `requests` and `limits` are specified on `container` level, and NOT on `pod`/`deployment` level. Why is that relevant?

Running istio (in our case, managed istio on GKE), the container is not alone in the "workload", much rather it also has `istio-init` (which is terminated soon after starting) plus `istio-proxy`.

And these additional containers apply their own limits & resources, in the current pod I am looking at for example:

```
Limits: 
  cpu: 2
  memory: 1Gi
Requests:
  cpu: 100m
  memory: 128Mi
```

on `istio-proxy` (using: `kubectl describe pods <podid>`)

This indeed explains why the WHOLE deployment has 2 cpu more in the limit as expected.